# How to restrict Apache Nutch to crawl language specific Documents only

Tags: apache, web-crawler, filtering, nutch

I am using apache Nutch 2.3 and I want to crawl only those documents from web that are in some specific language suppose Arabic or atleast documents should conatins some string in Arabic.

```
`So is there any option in crawler to do this job?`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Nutch. In your nutch xpathfilterconf, you can specify a language field name, and give it the appropriate xpath expression for whatever websites you're crawling.

Then, inside your XPathIndexingFilter, you can filter on the language field.

Alternatively, if the sites you are crawling don't have their language anywhere in the javascript, you can add a field name for the sites bodytext/main text, and then add some checking in the indexing filter to see if it contains Arabic text.

Comment: Can you explain it as I am not familiar with apache nutch too much i.e What do you mean by xpathfilterconf, where to specifiy a language field etc.